# Dequeue a Priority Queue

Tags: priority-queue

Elements dequeued from a priority queue follow the rule that:

Priority[i] >= Priority[i - 1]

But if many elements have the same priority, in what order should they be dequeued?
Should the element that was enqueued first be dequeued first or doesn't it matter?
I know this most likely depends on implementation and usage, but I'm looking for the textbook priority queue answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue should definitely be FIFO, that is its nature. The priority queue changes the queue aspect slightly in that it lets higher priority items through in preference to lower ones, but that shouldn't change the basic nature of the queue.

I've seen implementations that profess to be queues but do not follow the FIFO rules. I prefer a different name for them to better specify the behaviour (such as priority bags).

In a queue (even a priority one), items with the *same* priority should be extracted in the same order they were inserted.

In other words, inserting `A2 B2 C2 D1` (number is priority) should result in the processing as `D1 A2 B2 C2`.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I've always thought. I got a bit confused since most C# implementations I found while browsing the net didn't care in which order the elements were returned as long as the priority rule was correct.

Comment: I forget, do heap implementations of priority queues have that nature by default?

Comment: JAB: No, I'm pretty sure they don't.

Comment: With a HeapBased PriorityQueue you usually cannot guarantee insert order for objects of same priority.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a textbook answer.  Absent any other information, it could be done as a straight FIFO (within items of the same priority), or undefined, or other behavior.

Other implementations provide the enqueuer the ability to specify additional information that can be used during dequeue to break ties.